# error occurred in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Webview loading fails with the following error

`Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://www..com, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://www.website.com}`

My Code:

```
   webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    webView.delegate = self
    let url = NSURL(string: "www.amazon.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    view.addSubview(webView)

 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {


    return true
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("webview is start loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("webview is finish loading")
}
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print("webview loading error\(error)")
}
```

Comment: you need to add `http://` schema to url. `let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.amazon.com")`

Comment: it's working thanQ so much igor Bidiniuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "http://www.amazon.com" or "https://www.amazon.com"